# Good book on non-Eucledian geometry with linear algebra approach

Tags: geometry, book-recommendation, noneuclidean-geometry

Does anyone know of a good textbook on non-Eucledian geometry, which approaches geometry by using mostly linear algebra (e.g., projections, dot product, cross product, etc.)? I've looked at the "classical" book by Marvin Greenberg, but it doesn't appear to be using much linear algebra there.

One example of a spherical geometry problem which uses vectors (and thus linear algebra machinery is used for solution):

> Let $u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}(1, 1, -1)$ and $v = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 0, 1)$. Find the point $w\in \mathbb{S}^2$ such that $L_w$ is the line through $u$ and $v$. [Here $L_w$ is the spherical line with normal vector $w$].

I'd appreciate it very much if there's a person who knows of such a good textbook, or maybe even more than one.

Comment: There are 2 non-Euclidean geometries : spherical (sum of angles of  triangle > $\pi$, and hyperbolic (sum < $\pi$). Usually when one refers to spherical geometry, one does not use the term non-Euclidean, but that's not the most important. The point is that doing 3D rotations and so on is not doing "spherical geometry". Thus, "spherical geometry" is definitely not the right keyword. Look for a book on Linear Algebra with geometrical applications such as the ones by Gilbert Strang.

Comment: not very sure but did you have a look at Patrick Ryan's "Euclidean and Non euclidean geometry"  (CUP 1986 isbn 0-521-27635-7 I think it is close to the approach you are looking for, let me know when you find a better one :)

Comment: @JeanMarie yes, rotations are not "doing geometry" as such, but the sample problem in my post seems like a simple problem whose solution consists of doing geometry.